# VS 2017 on Windows 10 Downgrading to Mono 5.16

Tags: mono

I am new to mobile app development and ran into an issue with Mono being upgraded with my VS 2017 in windows 10 machine.

Its now upgraded to Mono 5.18 and it would not pair with the Mac. I cannot upgrade the MAC to have 5.18 (I have tried and failed) as the current code would not compile. We are upgrading the versions in our app currently but right now I want to downgrade my windows 10 VS 2017 to have Mono 5.16.

I dont seem to have a clue on where to download 5.16 Mono and install it. I am unsure if I will need to remove MOno 5.18 from my PC.

Any guidance/pointer with this regard will really help.

Comment: Are you talking about `Xamarin.iOS` pairing? As that version needs to match between Windows/macOS for Xamarin-based development.

Comment: Yes I am talking about that. My question is can I downgrade in windows in order to pair with Mac